# Why does my React app not working on Chrome and Opera?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, opera

I made a single page application with [React](https://reactjs.org/) which works in Firefox, IE, and Edge, but fails in Chrome and Opera. All of the UI stuff works wonderful and everything design related behaves good except the functionality that I made with React.

---

***[This is a link to the files if you want to try them out](https://github.com/cristiAndreiTarasi/React_App)***

---

I want to find out how can I make the app work correctly across all aforementioned browsers and find what the problem is.

Comment: You can get more help in Stack overflow.

Comment: To make this a question suitable for [so], please describe what is supposed to happen and what actually happens. “It’s not working” is not an error description.